# Change label forecolor dynamically in repeater based on db value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a string value that is returned from the database. the value will always either be "Red" or "Green". I am trying to change the forecolor of a label in my repeater based on this string value. If the value is "Red" the forecolor of the label should be red and visa versa.

I try by using this code in my asp page:

```
 ForeColor='<%# Eval("Color")%>'
```

however I get the flowing error:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

I have had a similar problem before by trying to set the width of an image dynamically and ended up casting the value like this:

```
<asp:Image 
  ID="Image1" 
  runat="server" 
  Width='<%# System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.Parse(Eval("ImageSize").ToString()) %>'
  ImageUrl="~/Images/ProgressBar.jpg"/>
```

The problem is how do I use the same technique with a system color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ForeColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.forecolor.aspx) needs a [`Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) object not a string.

So you could use [`ColorTranslator.FromHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx):

```
 ForeColor='<%# Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("Color").ToString())%>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 style='color:<%# Eval("Color")%>'
```

instead